# When open a productin multi-store website it redirects to 404 - page not found

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, multistore, store-view, administration

I have **Multi-Store Magento Website**, that is managed by **only One Admin**

in one of its store website,

when i click on product name, it redirects me to **404 page**.

what can be the problem ?

Comment: What is the URL of the page called? Did you enable mod_rewrite, do you have a .htaccess and rewrites?

Comment: There could be many problems. Enable developer mode & php error display; check Magento logs; do some debugging and give an indication to help us help you.

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 1):

Where are you viewing the product from?

If you've hard coded the display of a specific product, then perhaps you can see it to click because you've hard coded it in the template, but when you click it, the respective catalogue URL rewrite does not exist - and so 404s.

Check the product is viewable via a non rewritten URL. Eg.

```
http://www.example.com/catalog/product/view/id/XXX/
```

Replace XXX with the entity id of the product (not the sku!)

If that doesn't work, then the product isn't either

1. Enabled for that website
2. Set to be visible in catalogue

If it does work, then you just need to rebuild your catalogue URL rewrites index.

Also try accessing it via the bootstrap just to rule out web server rewrites

```
   http://www.example.com/index.php/catalog/product/view/id/XXX/
```

If that works, check your web server config for rewrites.

Comment: For Multi Website, is necessary for creating  Symbolic link

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps until the problem is solved or you reach the end of the list.

1. Clear the cache (contents of folder var/cache)
2. If you have other cache systems (full page cache for example) clear
   them
3. Check if the product is assigned to that website.
4. Check if the product is enabled.
5. Check if the visibility on that website is 'catalog' or 'catalog,
   search'.
6. Save the product again in the admin.
7. Rebuild all your indexes. There might be a problem with the url
   rewrites.

Comment: Everything done already, these steps are basic to be followed when any result not come-out.

Comment: can you provide a link to the website? maybe it helps.

Comment: Please give me your email, i send you there.

Answer (score 0):

You're using multi-store, do you have a discrete `MAGE_RUN_CODE` or `MAGE_RUN_TYPE` per store?

Do you have these being set correctly when accessing your store?
If you're able to successfully get the home page but not product pages check for redirect's or changes to the domain that may impact the run codes.

Ways to set these:

1. Directly in your `index.php`, e.g. a case statement based on `HTTP_HOST` or domain name - passing them directly to `Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);`.
2. In your Apache virtualhost (or similar) per domain using `SetEnv`.
3. In your .htaccess (if Apache) with some regex e.g. `SetEnvIf Host .*example.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=example`

With all of these options you need to make sure your logic in 1. or 3. includes the range of domains/hosts for each store.
In 2. Check your the domains Apache is listening on to make sure it covers all that Magento is serving/redirecting on.

If this isn't the issue, assuming you're using Apache, it often helps to temporarily set your [LogLevel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#loglevel) to something more verbose like `debug` to see exactly what's going on at the server level before Magento gets involved.

Comment: If the product is viewable, surely the store code is already set to be able to see the product to click?

Comment: It's certainly possible. What if the Apache VirtualHost is serving on example.com and www.example.com. But the store code has been only mapped correctly for example.com, maybe bad regex that doesn't take subdomains in to account. Magento is set to `base_url` of www.example.com. So you hit example.com, the store displays and it works but all the generated URLs are www.example.com, so they'll result in a 404.

Comment: Eh? If Magento loads the wrong store view - then its on page links will be from that store irrespective of what is in the browser URL. Magento's URL's are not relative to the current domain in the address bar, they are dictated by the currently loaded store configuration. Hence the use of `$this->getUrl()`

Comment: For Multi Website, is necessary for creating  Symbolic link